# NameError (uninitialized constant Search::Listings) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked at all the posts about errors like this and none seem to be similar to mine. I am getting the error `'uninitialized constant Search::Listings'` whenever I try to use my has_many association from Search to Listing (those are the class names) in the form of `search.listings.count` in _search_list.html.erb under /app/views/searches.

Yes, the filenames are search.rb and listing.rb and are in app/models.

Here is the code for each class and the file that I run the code in:

listing.rb

```
    # == Schema Information
#
# Table name: listings
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  description      :text
#  price            :float
#  pricing          :string
#  title            :string
#  url              :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#  listings_poll_id :integer
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_listings_on_listings_poll_id  (listings_poll_id)
#

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listing_searches
  has_many :searches, through: :listing_searches
  has_many :users, through: :searches
end
```

search.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: searches
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  keywords   :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  user_id    :integer
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_searches_on_user_id  (user_id)
#

class Search < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :listing_searches
  has_many :listings, through: :listing_searches

  # Validations done before saving.
  validates_presence_of :keywords
  validate :validate_keywords

  def validate_keywords
    entry = Search.find_by(user_id: user_id, keywords: keywords)
    if entry
      errors.add(:keywords, "Those keywords are already being used by you.")
    end
  end
end
```

listing_search.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: listing_searches
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  listing_id :integer
#  search_id  :integer
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_listing_searches_on_listing_id  (listing_id)
#  index_listing_searches_on_search_id   (search_id)
#
class ListingSearch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :searches
  belongs_to :listings
end
```

_search_list.html.erb:

```
<% @searches.each do |search| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= search.keywords %></td>
    <td><%= search.listings.count %></td>  --This line here is the cause
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', search %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_search_path(search) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', search, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I have tried moving the code to the searches controller and I get the same error.

I have tried adding 'source' to the has_many associations.

I have tried specifying adding the 'class' option to the associations.

NOTE: I am using Ruby Mine to edit the code (command line to run) and I notice that the IDE is saying "Unable to find associated Rails Model for ':listings' association field", but I've read that it is an IDE bug so I haven't been worried about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using singular in the belongs_to of listing_search.rb

`belongs_to :search
 belongs_to :listing`